# sbt-conductr zip name from bundle:dist

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm run sbt build with bundle:dist (plugin sbt-conductr)
after build sbt conductr generate zip archive:
name-archive-1.0-version-25cb8d75d73bc...11d.zip
How set archive name without 25cb8d75d73bc...11d???

I want to publish an artifact in an artifactory, but I can not specify the exact name of this artifact

```scala
val myZipTask = taskKey[File]("return the bundle:dist-zip file")
myZipTask := {
    //how get name zip archive, created in bundle:dist?
    file(filename)
}; addArtifact( Artifact("bundle", "zip", "zip"), myZipTask)
```

Comment: this code in build.sbt

Answer (score 1):

The `bundle:dist` task from that plugin returns the file it writes, so you can just call `(dist in Bundle).value` in your code to get that file reference. But `addArtifact` expects a reference to a task returning a file, so in your case:

```
addArtifact(
  Artifact("bundle", "zip", "zip"), 
  dist in Bundle
)
```

Comment: it's doesn't work:
`
build.sbt:111: error: overloaded method value addArtifact with alternatives:
(artifact: sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.librarymanagement.Artifact],taskDef: sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[java.io.File]])sbt.Def.SettingsDefinition <and>
(a: sbt.librarymanagement.Artifact,taskDef: sbt.TaskKey[java.io.File])sbt.Def.SettingsDefinition
cannot be applied to (sbt.librarymanagement.Artifact, sbt.File)
addArtifact(
^
`

Comment: As you can see from the error, `addArtifact` expects a reference to a task returning a file, not the file itself. So we don't even need to call `.value`. I fixed the answer.